# How is the use of OLS in estimating ARCH(q) models justified?

Tags: least-squares, garch, arch

So when estimating ARCH(q) model, some procedures go like estimating first AR(q) model using OLS and then using OLS again against error terms of AR(q).

But ARCH suggests heteroskedasticity, and OLS is inefficient when heteroscedasticity exists. So why is the use of OLS here justified?

Comment: it's not, but MLE would be slower to estimate

Comment: As you say, OLS is inefficient but it is still consistent, and as @Arhur B. correctly mentioned, OLS is faster to estimate.